# TypeError: ReferenceError: annonces is not defined? ionic app

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am receiving

> Uncaught TypeError: ReferenceError: annonces is not defined.` error on the recharge of a certain page of my ionic app.

I want to send the id of the "annonce" selected in the details page to list all the details of this item

The error comes up after the page was reloaded.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIOSv.jpg)
what should i do now for resolve this problem :/

service.js

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Annonces', function($http, $q) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON arra
    var dfd = $q.defer();
      $http.get("/php/annonces.php").then(function(response){
        annonces = response.data;
        console.log(annonces);
        dfd.resolve(annonces);   
        });
  return {
    all: function(){
       return dfd.promise;
      },
     get: function(annonceId) {
         
         $http.get("/php/annonces.php").then(function(response){
        annonces = response.data;
        }); 
          for (var i = 0; i < annonces.length; i++) {
        if (annonces[i].id === parseInt(annonceId)) {
            console.log(annonces[i]);
          return annonces[i];
          
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
```

controller.js

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AnnoncesCtrl', function($scope, allannonces) {
  
   $scope.annonces = allannonces;

})

.controller('AnnonceDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Annonces) {
  $scope.annonce = Annonces.get($stateParams.annonceId);
  console.log($scope.annonce);
  
});
```

app.js

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  
  $stateProvider
.state('annonces', {
      url: '/annonces',
  
          templateUrl: 'templates/annonces.html',
          controller: 'AnnoncesCtrl',
          resolve: {
        allannonces: function(Annonces) {
          return Annonces.all(); }
      }
        }
    )
 
 .state('details', {
      url: '/annonces/:annonceId',
          templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
          controller: 'AnnonceDetailCtrl'

        }
    )
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/annonces');

});
```

annonce.html

```html
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-remove-animate  item-icon-right" ng-repeat="annonce in annonces|filter:searshing" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/annonces/{{annonce.id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{annonce.img}}">
        <h2>{{annonce.titre}}</h2>
        <p>{{annonce.prix}}</p>
        <p>{{annonce.description}}</p>
        <p>{{annonce.date_creation}} {{annonce.region}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

details.html

```html
<div class="item item-divider" style="white-space: normal;padding: 4px;">
            
            <span style="padding-bottom: 4px;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight:bold;color:#346f96;font-size: 12px;">{{annonce.titre}}</span>
            <div style="display: block">
                <span style="color:#666; font-size: 10px;">{{annonce.date_creation}} {{annonce.region}} </span>
                <span style="color: #ff942a;font-weight: bold;margin-bottom: 5px;padding:4px;font-size: 14px; position: absolute;right: 0px;">
                    {{annonce.prix}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your factory `annonces = response.data;` where is annonces defined?

Comment: I have to defined? where can i defined it ?